# Does angularJs validation work in safari?

Tags: validation, angularjs, safari

I have implemented the from which works in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but don't know why it's not working in Safari ..

Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s9KvEctjr6inFRT9e90x?p=preview).

Comment: I have also the same problem. Please help me.

Comment: Plunker doesn't work very well for me in Safari, I have to type each character twice just to get it to show up once - it also runs extremely slow for me.  Could this be getting in the way of whether or not your test works?  Its fine in Chrome and Firefox though.

Comment: my test file code doesn't work at safari on  localhost as well ...:(

Comment: What **exactly** is wrong with it?

Comment: @Steve validation dont work in safari.. very annoying !!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "validation works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Safari" because as far as I can see it doesn't work in Chrome either because you haven't set `novalidate` attribute on the `form` tag which is required if you want to disable HTML validation and use Angular validation.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could explain what exactly should happen when validation works, because it's not visible where and how are you actually handling and displaying the validation errors.

Comment: I suspect you're running into an issue that also happens on fiddle relating to the use of post.  Check out this example and see the hack that's in the css:  http://jsfiddle.net/rabidGadfly/CUzbs/  and a discussion of the issue here:  https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/132

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug using Safari and if css contains:
-webkit-transition: border-color, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
(for example: form-controll in bootstrap uses it)

The form validation becomes invalid forever.

I used Safari on PC so I have no idea if it is also happen in Mac.

Comment: sorry guys, this is exactly what I was looking for.